# Find the pdf of y=x^2+1

Tags: probability-theory

I have a random variable X with pdf

```
(-1     0     1     2)
(1/4   1/2   1/8   1/8)
```

and I need to find the pdf of Y = X^2 + 1.

So by squaring X and adding 1 I obtain values 1, 2, 5 for the X vector. But how should I calculate the corresponding probabilities?

```
 (1  2  5)
 (?  ?  ?)
```

Thank you.

Comment: For each possible value of $X^2+1$ you need to find the corresponding value(s) of $X$ and their probabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply add the associated probabilities of $X$ for each of the given values which you squared and added $1$ to.
$$(1,2,5) \Rightarrow (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8})$$

Comment: So it's like having a mapping (old value) -> (new value)  for every vector component and the probabilities stay the same, and when we have overlapping (new values) we add the probabilities from the corresponding (old values) ?

Comment: Yes exactly like that. This is because $P(f(X)=f(x))=P(X=x)$.